# Python Vertical array? to C#

Tags: c#, python, arrays

How do I rewrite this line of python in C#? I'm in the process of trying to convert a python script to C# and I'm in need in some help. I just don't have any experience in Python really and these types of arrays are totally new to me. When I try to return the posVec I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convery type 'double' to 'Rhino.Geometry.Vector3d'". What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
posVec = dSorted[0][1]
```

The full method with this line in it is

```
    // find a new vector that is at a 90 degree angle
    public Vector3d GetDirection()
    {
        // define dictionary
        Dictionary<double, Vector3d> d = new Dictionary<double, Vector3d>();

        Vector3d[] arrPts = new Vector3d[] {
            new Vector3d(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3d(-1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3d(0, 1, 0),
            new Vector3d(0, -1, 0),
            new Vector3d(0, 0, 1),
            new Vector3d(0, 0, -1) };

        _vec = Vec;
        _vec.Unitize();

        // find the distance between the self vec position and one of the 6 90 degree vectors
        // create a dictionary that matches the distance with the 90 degree vector

        for (int i = 0; i < arrPts.Length; i++)
        {
            double dist = Math.Sqrt(
                ((_vec.X - arrPts[i].X) * (_vec.X - arrPts[i].X)) +
                ((_vec.Y - arrPts[i].Y) * (_vec.Y - arrPts[i].Y)) +
                ((_vec.Z - arrPts[i].Z) * (_vec.Z - arrPts[i].Z)));

            d.Add(dist, arrPts[i]);
        }

        Vector3d[] dSorted = d.Values.ToArray();
        var posVec = dSorted[0][1];
        return posVec;
    }
```

Comment: In C# you can have Both type of arrays: arr[x,y] and arr[x][y]

Comment: In C# you got the option between Multidimensional and jagged arrays. Personally I dislike the Multidimensional style, but that is a mater of personal preference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm rewritten things to `var posVec = dSorted[0][1];` and I'm not getting an error on that line, but what is the actual type of var posVec? Also I'm trying to return posVec, which should be a Vector3d but I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convery type 'double' to 'Rhino.Geometry.Vector3d'". What am I doing wrong?